# Receiving ByteArray data from API through Retrofit2 causes error in my Android App

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm calling an API in my Android app to receive this ByteArray from the server [Picture of ByteArray data from server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hm16z.png)

I'm using Retrofit2 in order to call the API, and in doing so I've had to specify the Response type. When I specify the Response type to be ByteArray,

```
@GET("api/getImage")
suspend fun getImage(@Query("user_id") user_id: String
): Response<ByteArray> // This is in my API Class

suspend fun getImage(user_id: String): Response<ByteArray> {
    return RetrofitInstance.api.getImage(user_id)
}` // This is in my Repository accessed through ViewModels
```

I encounter this error " java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $".

So then I tried to receive the Retrofit2 Response as a String type

```
@GET("api/getImage")
suspend fun getImage(@Query("user_id") user_id: String
): Response<String> // This is in my API Class

suspend fun getImage(user_id: String): Response<String> {
    return RetrofitInstance.api.getImage(user_id)
}` // This is in my Repository accessed through ViewModels
```

instead and then convert it to Bytes, but I encounter a "com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Expected value at line 1 column 56 path $" instead.

If it helps, here's my Retrofit Object I refer to in api calls:

```
object RetrofitInstance {

private val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().apply {
    addInterceptor(MyInterceptor())
    addInterceptor(HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY))
}.build()

private val retrofit by lazy {
    val gson = GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()
    Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .client(client)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .build()
}

val api : ApplicationAPI by lazy {
    retrofit.create(ApplicationAPI::class.java)
}
```

}

Would really appreciate the help in debugging this error

Comment: Isnt that just a file? Try with byte/Bytes. No ByteArray.

Comment: If you are downloading an image file than please say so. Or what else?

Comment: @blackapps I think changing it to Byte type worked! but now I'm getting this error "com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "������..."

Comment: Yes. That does not surprise me. You? And what does Gson with an image?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand? I'm fairly new at Android and Programming, could you please help explain

Comment: @blackapps Forgot to tag ^

Comment: Hi @blackapps I'd really appreicate your advice on overcoming this error please :D

Comment: I have no idea what you want to do with json on an image. Sorry.

Comment: @blackapps I don't. I just want to use the receive the bytes and set it to an image. I don't know why there is a JsonSyntaxException